# Visual Studio 2019 not recognizing compiling react typescript files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a webapp using Visual Studio 2019, C# on the back end and Typescript and Reactjs on the front end.

The issue that I am having is that the program builds and compiles but the updates that I do in the tsx files do not update in the corresponding js files. The tsx files do not seem to compile

There are no errors in my error list just warnings from C#. When I change code in the cs files the backend does update.

When I directly update the js files, the webapp updates. For example adding an alert will now show in the web app.

Here is my tsconfig file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "ES2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I can't really find much on the internet about this and it's difficult to know what to do since there are no errors.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I am still having this issue, sometimes intellisense will stop working all together. My compile work around has been this command in the src folder using command prompt:

```
npx tsc index.tsx --jsx react
```

Comment: Does your project have a build setup for your typescript app? Depending on what project type and your setup, building the typescript might be a separate manual step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did some guess work and digging and found out that visual studio didn't create a build file for me in comparison to my other projects. So as a bandaid solution right now I'm using the command "npx tsc index.tsx --jsx react". This compiles my files and then afterwards I run the solution in visual studio. It's a bit of a headache but for now it will do.